# MariaDB 10.4.10 ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, macos, mariadb, homebrew

I understand that in MariaDB 10.4.1 the mysql.user table was replaced by mysql.global_priv table. [The documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqluser-table/) says "mysql.user is now a view". When I login to a fresh install (using homebrew on os x) as root using socket connection I do not see this view. This is causing my GUI (sequel pro) to not work. Am I missing a setup step that creates this backwards-compatible view?

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select * from mysql.user;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist:ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17780630/table-mysql-user-doesnt-existerror)

Comment: I don't believe that answers it. I do now believe this is permissions related. MariaDB has two "all powerful" users, root and the user who installed it. When I login as the user who installed it (also the user who owns all the data directories) I can see that view.

Comment: Ok, now I can see it as both root and my local user and I swear I haven't changed anything. *sigh*.

Comment: Sometimes we don`t have answers why it stopped working all of a sudden, why it started working again without doing anything. This is the beauty of programming.

Comment: Check the GRANTs.

Comment: Same problem here. Fresh Homebrew install, log in with `sudo mysql -uroot` using socket authentication, and both `SELECT * FROM mysql.user` and `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` yield this frustrating error. I haven’t changed anything either, but the view remains stubbornly non-shown-up for me. :-(

Comment: (When I log in as the ‘other’ user, I get the same error, and when I try `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`, I am told that `mysql.columns_priv` also does not exist. \*sigh\* indeed.)

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be what was causing the issue for you, but it just fixed it for me – although I thought I’d checked up and down, back and front, it still turned out to be a permissions issue.

In my case, it was not only `mysql.user` which was reported as missing, but also `mysql.columns_priv` (when I tried flushing privileges). I could `use mysql` just fine, but `show tables` after that gave me the following error:

> ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of './mysql/' (errno: 13 "Permission denied")

That didn’t immediately make sense to me, but it apparently means that the `mysql` data directory is not readable by the `_mysql` user used by the MariaDB server.

I have MariaDB running as a Homebrew service, so I looked in the MariaDB MXCL plist file (located in your Homebrew Cellar folder; for me that’s `/usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.4.10_1/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist`): under the key `ProgramArguments`, there should be a `--datadir` argument which specifies which directory MariaDB uses to store data. Mine is `/usr/local/var/mysql`, which I’m guessing is standard.

In my case, I had previously had a regular (i.e., non-MariaDB) installation of MySQL 5.6 that had used the same data directory, which was probably the culprit – when I looked at the permissions on that directory, it was owned by my own user, and the `_mysql` user only had read permissions.

Once I gave `_mysql` read and write permissions on that folder, lo and behold, my `mysql.user` view, along with everything else in the `mysql` database, suddenly sprang into view and worked exactly as it’s supposed to.