# Drop user without a name from sql database

Tags: sql, mariadb

Executing the following command

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select distinct user from mysql.user;
```

results in

```
+-------------+
| User        |
+-------------+
| app_user    |
|             |
| test_u      |
| mariadb.sys |
| root        |
+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

So I have probably created a user with no name, correct? Perhaps by using a wrong syntax in the past. Question is how to `drop` the user? Something like the following doesn't seem to work:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> drop user ' ';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation DROP USER failed for ' '@'%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I stumbled upon [mysql.user does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52672118/4465153). During the execution of `mysql_secure_installation` the terminal states

> By default, a MariaDB installation has an anonymous user, allowing
> anyone to log into MariaDB without having to have a user account
> created for them.  This is intended only for testing, and to make the
> installation go a bit smoother.  You should remove them before moving
> into a production environment.

```
Remove anonymous users? [Y/n] Y 
... Success!
```

So this *' '*  user is equal to the anonymous user described here. Running `select distinct user from mysql.user;` after the removal of anonymous users.

Results in

```
+-------------+
| User        |
+-------------+
| app_user    |
| test_u      |
| mariadb.sys |
| root        |
+-------------+
```

So probably this ' ' user was already there.

Answer (score 0):

`drop` is used to remove tables https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-table.html, `DROP TABLE User`

Try `DELETE FROM User WHERE User.user = ' '`

Comment: Goin in the right direction I think. However I could not figure out to make it work for my situation as;
`MariaDB [(none)]> DELETE FROM User WHERE User.user = ' ';`
Results in `ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected`
Connecting to a database first 
`MariaDB [company]> select distinct user from mysql.user;
*SOME RESULTS*`
`MariaDB [company]> DELETE FROM User WHERE User.user = ' ';
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'company.user' doesn't exist`