# MySQL version 5.6.23 not allowing me to create a new user/grant privileges

Tags: mysql, database

It looks like the reason that I'm having this issue is because I was playing with the drop function and ran DROP DATABASE mysql and test... I think I need to reset mysql to default. What's the best way to do that? The instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911115/how-to-recover-recreate-mysqls-default-mysql-database) didn't work for me.

----my original question---

I'm trying to create a new user and grant them access in my database but I keep getting a syntax error. I can't see any syntax issues with what I am entering. 
I'm using MySQL version 5.6.23.

Here is a screenshot of the issue:
[image]

Here is the command I entered into MySQL:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON simple_cms_development.* TO ‘simple_cms’@’localhost’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘mypassword12345’;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '‘mypassword12345’' at line 1

Any advice?

Comment: You have weird quote characters.

Comment: sorry, that was me experimenting to see if it makes a difference.  I get this error what I type it correctly:

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON simple_cms_development.* TO 'simple_cms'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword12345';
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
mysql>

Comment: I was under the impression that using grant creates a new user and simultaneously grants them privileges. . ?

Comment: Did you drop the `mysql` database or `mysql.user` table?

Comment: I was playing with drop function and did drop the mysql database and then learned that it just comes standard with mysql. I added it back by entering CREATE DATABASE mysql but I'm guessing that doesn't just bring back all the functionality I wiped out. I also dropped test database. . is there a way to just rest mysql to what it was before I started messing with things?

Comment: also here's what's in there now:

Comment: mysql> show databases;
+------------------------+
| Database               |
+------------------------+
| information_schema     |
| mysql                  |
| performance_schema     |
| simple_cms_development |
| test                   |
+------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong type of quote character, these are accented quotes often found in word documents.  Most likely copy and pasted from a website or similar.

I would suggest re-typing the querying but using the quote(') key on your keyboard.

The type of quote you want is a single up and down line, rather than bending towards the quote on both ends.  The same kind you see enclosing your password in the error message.

Comment: thats not the issue here. I was simply experimenting. I've tried it every which way, typing it from scratch, copy paste from word doc, etc. The issue is that I dropped the mysql db and test db when I was playing around. . Now I need to figure out how to uninstall mysql and reinstall it.