# MySQL table(space) exists but can't discard

Tags: mysql, tablespace

Since I had some problems with my database, I tried to drop the database. When that didn't work, I removed my database folder in C:/xampp/mysql/data. I used `SHOW TABLES` and it said no tables in my database.

Now the problem is, first time importing my database dump file, I got the following problem:

```
 ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 2990: Table '`db`.`tbl`' already exists
```

I tried removing the table with the following query:

```
DROP TABLE tbl;
```

This gives the following error:

```
ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'db.tbl'
```

However, I tried to create it with the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
```

MySQL gives the following error:

```
ERROR 1813 (HY000): Tablespace for table '`db`.`tbl`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT.
```

I tried looking it up but I can't figure it out. Removing the .idb file causes the same problem eventually, I can't run `ALTER TABLE tbl DISCARD TABLESPACE;` because it'll give the error the table `db.tbl` doesn't exist.

Is there a way to fix this and what is the cause of it? I got these errors out of nowhere and it's frustrating

Comment: By default databases are now created as INNODB. These databases place parts of each table in the `C:/xampp/mysql/data/db` folder, **but also parts in** `C:/xampp/mysql/data/ibdata1` You have not yet removed the parts in `ibdata1`

Comment: Okay so how do I remove them from that?

Comment: [Read and inwardly digest](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107608/cannot-delete-db-table)

Comment: check this one mate,
looks like it'll give the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694168/error-tablespace-for-table-xxx-exists-please-discard-the-tablespace-before-imp

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried removing all databases except for mysql and performance_schema and remove ibdata1 but then it doesn't start MySQL up for me anymore

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911115/how-to-recover-recreate-mysqls-default-mysql-database

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks though I was able to use the backup folder as data folder and it worked again