# MySQL Error Even Purging and Reinstalling does not fix it

Tags: mysql

I accidentally began dropping Grant Tables from the "mysql" database I dropped several before I realised what I was doing.

When I tried accessing the mysql shell obviously it would no longer allow me access.

I decided to just purge and reinstall mysql.

However, now mysql will not startup.

When I run:

```
service mysql start
```

I get:

> Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
> See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Checking the logs under:

```
/var/log/mysql/error.log I get:
```

> [ERROR] [MY-013129] [Server] A message intended for a client cannot be sent there as no client-session is attached. Therefore, we're sending the information to the error-log instead: MY-001146 - Table 'mysql.component' doesn't exist

And

> [ERROR] [MY-010326] [Server] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.db' doesn't exist

Does anyone know I can regenerate these missing tables?

=====Edit=====

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf doesn't exist.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911115/how-to-recover-recreate-mysqls-default-mysql-database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover/recreate mysql's default 'mysql' database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911115/how-to-recover-recreate-mysqls-default-mysql-database)

Comment: @GarrGodfrey When I run: 

mysqldump --routines databasename > outfile.sql

I get:

mysqldump: Got error: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 104 when trying to connect

Comment: @GarrGodfrey And running: mysqld --initialize

gives me:

2021-10-13T19:56:20.679309Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) initializing of server in progress as process 288419
2021-10-13T19:56:20.681026Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2021-10-13T19:56:20.681030Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
2021-10-13T19:56:20.681077Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting

Comment: 2021-10-13T19:56:20.681177Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.3)  (Ubuntu).

Comment: show what you did to purge and reinstall

Comment: you probably need the answer from kungfooman. The long one about moving your db files out of data directory and recreating everything

Comment: @ysth: sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I have an issue with:

/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

It doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

From here:

[How to recover/recreate mysql's default 'mysql' database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911115/how-to-recover-recreate-mysqls-default-mysql-database)

I ran:

/etc/init.d/mysql stop
rm /var/lib/mysql -rf
mkdir /var/lib/mysql
chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
mysqld --initialize

But my /etc/mysql was a bit messed up so I purged mysql again. When I reinstalled everything is running okay now.